# Story: alien neighbours

Tags: story-identification

I remember that this story was set in countryside in America

- Protagonist is male
- He lives on a farm when new neighbours arrive; there are 3 of them - man, woman and their daughter.
- Those neighbours fix previously-abandoned farm quickly and become efficient workers.
- Later a reporter arrives to investigate this area, since it had shown higher yield that anywhere else
- Reporter suspects that there is something fishy about the recently-arrived family, and when he tries to leave town - he cant, since *his car gets magically turned around in an unnoticeable fashion halfway down the road*.
- It is strongly implied that the *new neighbours are alien, since their car, otherwise looking broken contains a box-like peace of shiny metal instead of engine* and a smoke generator-thingy like in toy trains.

I think this may be a Simak story, but I was unable to find the name.

Comment: His car didn't get "turned around" so much as "looped". That is, when he found himself heading back into the city, I think it was from the other side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably "[Neighbor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53623)" by Clifford D. Simak, as per [this review](http://sfpotpourri.blogspot.com/2014/09/1961-aliens-for-neighbours-simak.html).

> Calvin, Bert and Jingo tend their sprawling farms in Coon Valley. When a new family takes over the old Lewis farm, speculation runs among them and the other townies. Curiosity is piqued when it’s discovered that their fields are pest-free and well-watered, unlike the farm of the farming trio. Also, Reginald Heath, the new farmer, has a curious tractor and an equally as curious car. Ten years later, during which peace reigns, an unwelcome reporter comes to inquire about the valley’s peculiarities.

ISFDB shows it as having been collected in several locations including various editions of *The Worlds of Clifford Simak*, also released as *[Aliens for Neighbours](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18217934-aliens-for-neighbors)* in the UK, as well as *Astounding Science Fiction* June 1954 (available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v53n04_1954-06_cape1736#page/n107/mode/2up)) & *Best Science Fiction Stories of Clifford D. Simak* & *Space 1* & *Urania* #1091 (in Italian) & *Immigrant and Other Stories* & *Over the River and Through the Woods* & *The Big Front Yard and Other Stories*.